# Force downloading file in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have just finished my project and move to live server mean-while all contents and program are working very well on my Development section (XAMPP) and I have also moved this project to test on a live shared hosting server (Namecheap). all work good then until I purchase a VPS server and installed cpanel. When I uploaded my project and using php 7.3, things no longer are working right for file forcing download. Here is my code.

```
//* Download item zip files
public function downloadItemZipFiles($id)
{
    $settingsModel = new AdminPanel();
    $itemModel = new ItemsModel();
    $siteInfo = $settingsModel->getApplicationInfomations();
    $item = $itemModel->getItemByIdOnly($id);
    $name = $siteInfo->ss_name . '-' . $item->item_id . '-' . $item->item_slug.'.zip';
    $path = item_zip_file($item->item_id);

    if (is_file($path)) {
        if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        }

        $file = new \CodeIgniter\Files\File(strval($path));
        $mime = $file->guessExtension();
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)).' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private', false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($path);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not found";
    }
}
```

if I try to force download a file, I receive this browser error

> This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://www.codewigs.com/filex/download-item-zip-file/21 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: which is your CI version, please?

Comment: Codeigniter version 4

Comment: It might be a browser issue, the message seems to come from Chrome, please check with FF. You also might not have updated your htaccess file from http (dev) to https (prod) ?

Comment: @Vicket thanks for reply i try all my browsers Chrome, Opera, MS Edge same output this code work with the browder on the dev mode (Xampp) and also work on my test liver server (Namecheap) shared hoting untill i purchase my vps every thing went wrong. Some code same setup

Comment: check with your VPS provider if the SSL certificates are set correctly, open a support ticket with them, it looks clearly to be a configuration thing, since on shared hosting all went well.Also double-check the vPS php version! Even a different php.ini could be a problem

Comment: do you have any feedback ?

Comment: @vickel thanks the problem is due to my memory limit in my php.ini my memory limit is lower than d the file size am try to download.